How to embed all of youtube channel's videos in iframe? Example, please?
Just like embedding a video or playlist iframe, I want to embed a channel iframe, that is, all the vids from a channel.  Hopefully in order of date, descending.
I can successfully iframe embed a single vid or a created playlist of vids.  But, for a channel, I have tried every possible combination of
embed/
videoseries/
playlist
listType=user_uploads&list=[the channel's id]
listType=user_uploads&list=[the channel's @name w/wo "@"]

Here is my channel: https://www.youtube.com/@anacortesmusicproject4632
and the id: UC1LDNvBo-LY1CJYfqjHpVgw
I get "This video is unavailable"
The channel is public.
